# Создать на Azure веб-сайт с авторизацией и службой рассылки e-mail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, service, azure

Необходимо создать на Azure сайт + база + сервис рассылки писем по заданному алгоритму и расписанию . На сегодня есть веб-приложение на Azure + база данных SQL. Как подключить сервис рассылки? Использовать WebRole & WorkerRole или можно отдельно добавить службу, которая бы работала с базой данных? Нагрузка на сервер будет - до 100 небольших писем в день. Сервис планируется писать на .NET

Comment: А на сколько большая нагрузка ожидается на данный сервис? Как много писем? Как часто? Какого размера? В зависимости от этого ответ может вариироваться от возьми Azure Website уровня Free, до того, что нужна громадная архитектура с кучей микросервисов и тому подобное.

Comment: Так же было бы не плохо знать на чём вообще данный серис будет писаться...

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял, что уже имеется сайт который крутится на Azure Websites? В данном случае я бы порекомендовал вам использовать Azure WebJob. Они именно для таких целей и созданны. Azure WebJob можно будет захостить в том же пространстве, что и Azure Website и не переплачивать за это.

Если пишете на .NET, то там вообще для WebJobs есть [пакет расширений SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). Могу себе представить, что для данной цели мог бы использоваться TimeTrigger. Вообще Azure WebJobs это некий аналог сервиса в Windows, который лишь работает в Background'e и методично выполняет какую-то работу.

Ежели это должно быть мегаспаммерское приложение, для рассылки огромного коичества писем, то стоит задуматься над использованием Azure Worker Role. Так же этот вариант уместен в тех случаях, если не возможно избежать использование какого-либо софта, который необходимо установить на виртуальную машину.

Но боже упаси вас от использования простых виртуальных машин для этих целей. Это настоящий anti paatern в Cloud Computing. Ибо виртуальные машины стоят дороже, а ими ещё и самостоятельно управлять надо. Таким образом вы сознательно отказываетесь от всех благ облачной платформы. Виртуальные машины в Azure используют в основном лишь для миграции тех legacy-приложений в облако, которые не возможно переписать, но и просто забить на них нельзя. Ну или для всяческих потребностей инфраструктуры.

Answer (score 0):

В Azure есть возможность создать виртуальную машину. Подключаетесь к ней через remote десктоп, копируете из проводника свою программу рассылки и запускаете. Все будет работать как обычно на локальном компе.

Когда виртуальная машина станет не нужна, то не забудьте ее отключить.

Comment: Зачем тогда использовать облачные сервисы, если не использовать их преимущества? Так можно и простые VPS заказать.